# Paste HTML to Excel VSTO

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

Are there better ways to copy and paste html data into Excel sheet using VSTO/C# ?

I'm copying html data from a file, and trying to paste into Excel cell. But, I keep getting the exception **"Paste special method of range class failed"**.

I'm creating a new worksheet at run-time in a separate thread.

```
// Initialize in separate thread
Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(controller.Run));
thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
thread.Start();
```

In the thread run method,

```
// Worksheet name

    string workSheetName = String.Format("{0}_{1}", param1, param2);

    // Get worksheet data

    string reportContent = File.ReadAllText(filePath);

    // Create worksheet

   Excel.Worksheet newWorksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)Globals.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add();
           newWorksheet.Name = workSheetName;

    // Write report content to clipboard as html

    Clipboard.SetData(DataFormats.Html, reportContent);

   Thread.Sleep(2000);

   Excel.Range rng = newWorksheet.Cells[1, 1];

  rng.PasteSpecial(Excel.XlPasteType.xlPasteValues,  Excel.XlPasteSpecialOperation.xlPasteSpecialOperationNone,
 Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```

Comment: Kindly help ...any help appreciated. Have been at it for last 3 hours with no luck

Comment: If you only set the clipboard content and break there, can you paste manually into excel?  Seems like you may be setting the wrong clipboard format: all you're reading from the file is really just plain text.

Comment: I added an artificial delay in between my copy and paste, and it worked.